# How to get regular float32 geometry of a mesh compressed using gltfpack

Tags: three.js

I used mesh decimation using gltfpack with the command
`gltfpack -i input.glb -o output.glb -si 0.01`

this reduces my mesh geometry triangles by 99 percent.

Now my output.glb has geometry.position as an interleaved Buffer Attribute of data type unsigned Int 16. I am using ammo.js to make its physics body, which requires geometry as a regular float32 array. But my attempts to convert it by dividing by 2^32 - 1, 2^31 - 1 have failed.
I get the body but positioned with different size and position, and it doesn't align with the threejs rendered model.

Is there a way to a regular float32 array so that I can pass it to the createConvexHullPhysicsShape function of Ammo.js

I've added a sandBox that shows the issue. [issue](https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-cookies-4dmdfy?file=/src/index.js)

Comment: I would suggest opening a thread on the three.js forums (https://discourse.threejs.org/) rather than updating the question here with new problems. It seems like you are looking for more support with a project than just the Q/A format of Stack Overflow. :)

Comment: you're right, I've shifted it to a new thread (https://discourse.threejs.org/t/physics-body-of-mesh-showing-up-correctly-for-a-glb-but-not-for-another/43473)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Steps for quantizing and de-quantizing a normalized array can be found in the [`KHR_mesh_quantization`](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF/blob/main/extensions/2.0/Khronos/KHR_mesh_quantization/README.md#encoding-quantized-data) specification, equivalent to what hardware APIs will do. For int16 that would be:

```
float = max(int / 32767.0, -1.0)
```

This does assume that the values are *normalized*. In gltfpack I think that is an option. You can check `attribute.normalized` in three.js. If it is false there is no need for conversion, you can just use the values as-is.

Finally, note that if the buffer is interleaved, you will have to de-interleave, as the buffer might contain vertex attributes other than position.

---

> UPDATE: September 9, 2022

The positions this GLB do not actually appear to be normalized, in the WebGL sense. They are large integers, and there's an inverse scaling on the parent nodes that brings them back down into a smaller floating point range. You'll need to account for that when extracting positions from the Mesh to create a convex hull. For example —

```js
import { deinterleaveAttribute } from "three/examples/jsm/utils/BufferGeometryUtils.js";

function getVertexPositions(root) {
  const positions = [];

  root.updateMatrixWorld(true);

  root.traverse((obj) => {
    if (obj.type !== "Mesh") return;

    let position = obj.geometry.attributes.position;

    // de-interleave the array
    position = deinterleaveAttribute(position);

    // cast from Int16 to Float32
    position = new THREE.BufferAttribute(
      new Float32Array(position.array),
      position.itemSize,
      false
    );

    // apply mesh scaling to the positions array.
    position.applyMatrix4(obj.matrixWorld);

    positions.push(position);
  });

  return positions;
};
```

Result:

[image: 3d mesh outlined by convex hull physics collider]

Comment: I've added a demo for the issue in the question, please have a look.

Comment: Hi @AT3 — I've added a snippet of code above, you can use this instead of the current `dfs()` function in your sandbox, to gather the vertex positions from the scene.

Comment: I couldn't have figured out myself, thanks !